# Homework solving exponential equation, logarithmic equation and exponential equation.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I need help with three homework questions.¨

First one:

$$\sqrt{3x^2-2x-15}=x+1$$
I don't know how to get the right answer. The answer is supposed to be 4.
I get:
$$ 3x^2-2x-15=(x+1)^2$$
$$ 3x^2-2x-15=x^2+2x+1$$
$$ 2x^2-4x-14=0$$
$$ x^2-2x-7=0$$

$$ x_1=1+\sqrt8$$
$$ x_2=1-\sqrt8$$

Second question is:
$$ ln(x-7)-2ln(x-1)=-2ln5$$
where i come to this stage but don't know how to solve it
$$\frac{x-7}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{1}{25}$$

the answer is supposed to be   $x=11$ or $x=16$

Third question is $$9^x-4*3^x+3=0$$

I have come this far $$3^{2x}-4*3^x+3=0$$

answer is supposed to be $x=1$ or $x=0$

Comment: 1st question: when you went from $-15$ to $-14$ you should have gone to $-16$ instead.

Comment: Welcome to the site! In the future, please separate your questions into different posts.

Answer (score 0):

1) $-15 - 1 = -16$ not $-14$.

2) multiply by sides to get:  $25(x -7)  = (x - 1)^2$

3) $3^{2x} + 4*3^x + 3 = 0$.  Let $y = 3^x$ so to get $y^2 + 4y + 3 = 0$.  Easier?

Comment: I understand question 1) and 3) now thank you.

on question 2 I dont't understand how that helps me? shall I change forms to $$25x-175=x^2-2x+1$$?
I don't understand how that makes it easier.

Comment: You just need to solve for x, don't you?  $ 25(x−7)=(x−1)^2 \implies 25x−175=x^2−2x+1 \implies x^2 - 27x + 176 = 0 $ (if I didn't make any mistakes which I probably did.--- no, i didn't)